# Incorrect syntax, unable to use CHARINDEX

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing in SQL, trying to use CHARINDEX to split a field by the character '\'.

Possible entries for the column of interest will be of the following format:

J1\1

J1\2

J10\3

J11\40

I am trying to isolate the characters to the left of the backslash.

My query currently looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT

CASE
    WHEN C1_From.com_com_id = C2_From.com_id
        THEN C1_From.com_tag
END AS PP_From,

CASE
    WHEN C1_From.com_com_id = C2_From.com_id
        THEN CHARINDEX('\\', C1_From.com_tag)
END AS PP_From_INDEX,   

CASE
    WHEN C1_From.com_com_id = C2_From.com_id
        THEN LEFT(C1_From.com_tag,2)
END AS PP_From_CHOP,
```

I didn't include all the joins because I didn't think it was relevant in the context of incorrect syntax.

The first case will return the full string, i.e. 'J1\1', etc.

The second case 'should' return the index of the backslash.

Finally, the third case would return the string, chopped at the backslash.

Provided I can get CHARINDEX working, I would also like to be able to accomplish this using a single case rather than 3.

My problem is that when I try and run the query, I can an error saying "nvalid query. Incorrect syntax near '\'". What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help. Cheers

Full query, as requested:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    tew_cable.cab_tag,

    CASE
        WHEN L1_From.loc_loc_id = L2_From.loc_id
            THEN L1_From.loc_text       
    END AS Rack_From,

    CASE
       WHEN L1_From.loc_loc_id = L2_From.loc_id
            THEN L2_From.loc_text
        ELSE L1_From.loc_text
    END AS Compartment_From,

    CASE
        WHEN C1_From.com_com_id = C2_From.com_id
            THEN C1_From.com_tag
    END AS PP_From,

    CASE
        WHEN C1_From.com_com_id = C2_From.com_id
            THEN SUBSTRING(com_tag, 1, CHARINDEX('\', com_tag)-1)
    END AS PP_From_INDEX,   

    CASE
        WHEN C1_From.com_com_id = C2_From.com_id
            THEN LEFT(C1_From.com_tag,2)
    END AS PP_From_CHOP,

    CASE
        WHEN C1_From.com_com_id = C2_From.com_id
            THEN C2_From.com_tag
        ELSE C1_From.com_tag
    END AS Component_From

FROM tew_cable

    LEFT JOIN tew_location AS L1_From 
        LEFT JOIN tew_location AS L2_From 
            ON L1_From.loc_loc_id = L2_From.loc_id
        ON tew_cable.cab_loc_id_from = L1_From.loc_id

    INNER JOIN tew_cablewire 
        ON tew_cable.cab_id=tew_cablewire.caw_cab_id

    LEFT JOIN tew_wire
        ON tew_cablewire.caw_cab_id = tew_wire.wir_cab_id 
        AND tew_cablewire.caw_no = tew_wire.wir_caw_no  

    LEFT JOIN tew_component AS C1_From
        LEFT JOIN tew_component AS C2_From
            ON C1_From.com_com_id = C2_From.com_id
        ON C1_From.com_id = tew_wire.wir_com_idfrom
```

Comment: "\" is not an escape character in T-SQL, so you should just use a single "\" for `CHARINDEX`. That's one small part of your question.

Comment: @Nick_Camps can you run "SELECT SUBSTRING('J1\1', 1, CHARINDEX('\', 'J1\1')-1)" or does it throw an error?  If it does not throw an error then I think your syntax is probably different than what you have posted.

Comment: @hcaelxxam I ran the code, and received the error "Invalid query. Incorrect syntax near 'J1'." Even just running `SELECT SUBSTRING('J1\1', 1, 2)` returns the same error.

Comment: @NickCamps Are you running this in Management Studio or are you using C# or something?

Comment: @hcaelxxam I am using Solidworks Electrical Schematic, a database driven CAD software, to generate reports from the SQL back-end. I have a suspicion that the software has a limited set of functions it is allowing me to use.

Comment: @NickCamps Ah, that makes a lot more sense, this is probably a sql injection thing.  Try escaping all apostrophes and your slash. i.e. SELECT SUBSTRING(\'J1\\1\', 1, 2) and see if that works.